# Combine multiple streams not at the same time

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

Searching for a way to combine multiple streams into single stream but add each stream in different time without dropping the stream listeners.

My end goal is many to many that join in different times.

[image]

Example:

A and B Streams Join.

E and F start listen to D.

B send data that reach E and F.

A send data that reach E and F.

G start listen to D.

C Stream join.

A send data that reach E and F and G.

C send data that reach E and F and G.

Found that the right side (multiple listeners at different times) can be done by using `BehaviorSubject` but you cant add to it more streams without closing the last one.

And I found a lot of ways to marge streams but you have to marge all the streams at the same times and there is no way to add new one to the existing ones.

If we find a way to combine multiple streams at different times without drooping the listener we can use it like this since D can be used with `BehaviorSubject`

[image]

Comment: Try [`StreamGroup`](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/StreamGroup-class.html) from `package:async`.

Comment: Thanks it worked.
I have tested it before but it didn't worked because all stream got closed so `StreamGroup` got close as well and I didn't noticed. Also this time I have add `StreamGroup.broadcast`

Answer (score 1):

[`StreamGroup.broadcast`](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/StreamGroup-class.html) can do this, it is acting as H+D in my second picture.

It can

- Be listened to multiple times (like D in the second picture).
- Can combine multiple streams into one (like H in the second picture).

Please add [async](https://pub.dev/packages/async) to your packages for `StreamGroup`.

Example:

```
StreamGroup<int> streamGroup = StreamGroup.broadcast();
```

Than to add a stream use:

```
streamGroup.add(streamToAdd);
```

To listen to it use:

```
streamGroup.stream.listen((event) { })
```